# expand button for navigating to any given page number

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, pagination

Could you please provide an “expand button” so that I can see all the pages for a given profile? Currently, to navigate to page 8 I have to go to page 6 first.

Answer (score 2):

It's a workaround and a stretch of your mouse (or whatever navigation tool you use), but you can always directly enter the page number in the URL. It's by no means clean, but it is very effective and functional, and definitely saves you time and trouble when navigating particularly large numbers of pages.